# Spring аннотация @Value не внедряет свойство в много-модульном проекте

Tags: java, spring, properties

Я пишу web приложение на Java, это много-модульный maven проект. В нем два модуля mmmp-service и mmmp-web. Тот что mmmp-web собирается в war файл. Тот что mmmp-service собирается в jar. Модуль mmmp-web зависит от mmmp-service. В модуле mmmp-service имеется файл свойств application.property, в котором объявлено свойство app.service.url=какая-то строка. В этом же модуле (mmmp-service) это свойство внедряется через spring-аннотацию @Value. Но когда стартует приложение mmmp-servive spring не может найти это свойство и оставляет его равным null. Вопрос почему?

Класс настройки контекста и класс сервиса в который внедряется свойство модуля mmmp-service:

Это файл класса настройки контекста модуля mmmp-service

```java
package ru.monsterdev.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;

@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class AppConfig {
  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  }
}
```

Это файл класса сервиса модуля mmmp-service:

```java
package ru.monsterdev.servises.impl;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import ru.monsterdev.servises.IHttpService;

@Service
public class HttpService implements IHttpService {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpService.class);

  @Value("${app.service.url}")
  private String url;

  @Override
  public String getRequestBody(String param) {
    LOGGER.debug("URL is {}", url);
    return param;
  }
}
```

Класс модуля mmmp-web в котором вызывается сервис из модуля mmmp-service

```java
package ru.monsterdev.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import ru.monsterdev.servises.IHttpService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IntexController {
  @Autowired
  private IHttpService httpService;

  @GetMapping("/")
  public String indexAction(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("response", httpService.getRequestBody("Hello"));
    return "index";
  }
}
```

Есть предположение, что приложение mmmpweb.war не видит файл application.properties, потому что оно не лежит в его classpath, но дело в том, что модуль mmmpservice.jar лежит в WEB-INF/libs приложения mmmpweb.war, разве этого не достаточно?

Answer (score 0):

Задай его программно:

```java
package ru.monsterdev.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;


@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurator = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurator.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/application.properties", AppConfig.class));
        return configurator;
    }
}
```